# Django: Generate slug before save model

Tags: django, models

When i save the model from admin interface a first time i need to autogenerate the slug. I use `slugify` and `pre_save signal` and my slug field have `unique=True` option. But when i push save  button the object slugfield `raise validation error (Required field)` because field is unique, i think. I thought that pre_save goes before validation. Or i am wrong?

```
# models.py

class Slugified(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Post(Slugified):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Post)
def save_slug(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)
```

Comment: There is a 3rd party library: https://pythonhosted.org/django-autoslug/fields.html which works great too.

Answer (score 4):

The form automatically generated by the admin sees the `slug` field as a required field. The `pre_save` signal receiver works correctly, but the code never tries to save the model as the form doesn't validate.

The solution to this is to all blank values:

```
class Slugified(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, blank=True)
```

This way, the field is not required in the form and the slug gets set before the instance is saved.

Also, please note that your code does not correctly handle duplicate slugs. If two post titles generate identical slugs, an `IntegrityError` would be raised. This is easier solved in the `save` method than in the `pre_save` signal receiver:

```
class Slugified(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        while True:
            try:
                return super(Slugified, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError:
                # generate a new slug
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't saw the answer. Thank you, i will try this way! But for me is not so clear, what for you use "while True" construction